# Extract domo magic etl metadata for sql migration

Tags: domo

I am working on a requirement where we need to migrate the magic etl logic developed inside DOMO BI Tool to sql queries. Since I do not have experience working on DOMO so i am struggling to find answers to below questions. Please help with answers and supporting document links will be a great help.

1. Does Domo stores the sql version of its magic etl which can be accessed ?
2. Does Domo provide an option to export the magic etl metadata or access to magic etl metadata in any other way ?
3. If i have to convert a magic etl to equivalent sql , what could be the best/automated way ?

I checked the domo api documentation but could not find enough details related to above questions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To answer question #2, you can use the [Domo CLI](https://domo-support.domo.com/s/article/360043437733?language=en_US)'s `list-dataflow` command to export the Magic ETL configuration as a JSON file.

You might then be able to parse that output and recreate similar steps as SQL statements, though be aware of that Magic ETL tiles are discrete actions and several tiles might be consolidated into a single line of SQL. It's better to use the ETL as a guide to reproduce the logic of the dataflow rather than an exact translation.

Domo does allow creating MySQL DataFlows that are written in SQL - that might help prototype a solution to bridge between Magic ETL and querying a database directly.